# Is there any Jabber client that supports popups?

Tags: 14.04, jabber

we're using Jabber for communication in the office. Unfortunately I am replying very late to a lot of messages, as I just don't see them. To now I've tried Pidgin and Gajim, both have an option for "popup on new message". That's exactly what I want, when I get a new message then the chat window should pop up to the front.

But that option isn't working! Both clients just seem to ignore it (it works randomly with Pidgin and an extra plugin) and the only indicator I get for a new message is the blue envelope in the status bar. That envelope doesn't help me a lot, as it's also used by other programs.

Is this a limitation of Ubuntu, a failure in my configuration or just bad luck with the two clients I've tried to now?

Comment: `Empathy` the default client has preference for this. It is called `event in notification area`. You can disable it and see if that works for you.

Comment: @sagarchalise But it's not about disabeling it in the notification area, it's about not working popups even though there is a option for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `pidgin` on Ubuntu 14.04, which nicely pops up a message in the top right corner of the screen (as did `Empathy`, which I used before). I can't remember having set any specific preference to enable this. 
Moreover, when a new conversation starts, the conversation window pops up (or when the conversation is still open on a different virtual desktop the pidgin icon pops up in the sidebar on the left). Do you receive notifications in the top right corner for other events, like new e-mail messages?

Comment: Yes, I get the short popup in the top right, but that fades away. I need the actual conversation window to come to the front. That doesn't (always) happen.